# WebAPI/Json.NET - Force deserialization to fail if there are additional properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this json

```
{
   "state": "enabled"
}
```

to

```
class Setting 
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I have my Web API controller method:

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetSetting([FromBody] Setting setting)
    { 
         // not important 
    }
```

I would like to force deserialization to fail in case I receive the following json paylod in the request:

```
{
   "state": "enabled",
   "extra_key": "extra_value"
}
```

I 've tried setting up this in the webApi config:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = true;
```

However, this works only if I have additional content at the very end of the payload such as:

```
 {
 "state": "enabled",
}, "extra"
```

How can I force deserialization to fail in case I'm getting additional json properties?

Comment: For documentation of `MissingMemberHandling` see [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm).